# Create a UIView and grow it to fill screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, swift3, uicollectionview

I am making a weather up which consists of two main views. 
The first one is the main view, it has a scrollable UICollectionView which has cell that represent small weather cards. The second one, is a different view which has all the weather details shown in a more detail.

I want to create a UIView on top of the collection view and grow it to fill the screen. Sadly I keep failing and cannot find a proper way to do it.
When the cell is pressed, I want to create a UIView on top of the cell (getting it's position on the view) and then growing it to fill the screen.

[image: This is the main view.]

Where I intend to put the code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Cell [\(indexPath.row)] selected.")

    // Get cell position on screen:
    let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
    let cellRect = attributes?.frame
    let frameCellInSuperview = collectionView.convert(cellRect!, to: collectionView.superview)
    print("x: \(Double(frameCellInSuperview.origin.x)), y: \(Double(frameCellInSuperview.origin.y))")

    // Create a small UIView in the exact same position


    // Grow the UIView to fill the screen
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get current index frame against superview using this code :

```
   let theAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
   let cellFrameInSuperview:CGRect!  = collectionView.convert(theAttributes.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
```

Now create a UIView of same frame . Using this code :

```
var popView = UIView(frame: cellFrameInSuperview)
self.view.addSubview(popView)
```

Now animate view by updating frame :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
        popView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    })
```